# Can't upload an image with PHP on godaddy unless code in index.php page

Tags: php, html, upload

I'm trying to create a social networking site and want the users to be able to upload a picture of their choice. The following code works locally and ONLY if I have it in the main index.php file. But I need to have a link to another page for the users to upload the image. Godaddy support says I should be able to do it, but now deep into my second day I'm reaching out for help.

Here is the code:

```
if(isset($_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"])) {

$imageFile = ($_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"]);
$imageType = ($_FILES["fileUpload"]["type"]);
$validext = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$fileExt = pathinfo($imageFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
echo $fileExt . "<br>";
$ready = false;

if((($imageType == "image/jpeg") || ($imageType == "image/jpg") || 
  ($imageType == "image/png")) && in_array($fileExt, $validext)) {
    echo "was valid image<br>";
}else{
    echo "was not a valid image<br>";
    $ready = false;
}

if($_FILES["fileUpload"]["size"] < 500000) {
    $ready = true;
    echo "file size is " . $_FILES["fileUpload"]["size"] . "<br>";
}else{
    echo "file was TO BIG!<br>";
    echo "file size is " . $_FILES["fileUpload"]["size"] . "<br>";
    $ready = false;
}

if($_FILES["fileUpload"]["error"]) {
    echo "looks like there was an error: " . $_FILES["fileUpload"]["error"] . "<br>";
    $ready = false;
}

$targetPath = "images/".$imageFile;
$sourcePath =  $_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"];
if(file_exists("images/".$imageFile)) {
    echo "File already there <br>";
    $ready = false;
}

if($ready == true) {
    move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath);
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload file">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It's pretty standard. I don't know if the issue is with Godaddy or the code. I am not a PHP expert at all.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Again: this works if I call it index.php at the root site level, but if I name it anything else or move it anywhere else it won't work and it's very kludgie to put in index.php.

Thanks in advance. Someone must have run into this before...

Comment: what *exactly* happens if this code is in another file?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not very helpful. What do you expect to happen? What actually happens?  What error messages do you see? What do your logs say? What does `move_uploaded_file()` return?

Comment: You'r going to need to be more specific about what you tried, and what happens. The form action is set to "index.php", so if you move the code to another file, you will need to change the form action to reflect the files name and location.

Comment: @AlexHowansky: I tried to upload a file. I expected for it to upload. No error. Nothing. And no upload. When I put it in another file, i.e. upload.php it lets me pick a file a click the upload button and it just goes to index.php with no error, no upload, no nothing. That's why I'm here. I have nothing much to go on. Hoping someone else experienced the same.

Comment: if you put the code in upload.php, did you change the form action to upload.php?

Comment: @tim yes I did..

Comment: I finally got the code to work. The issue seems to be with the Jcrop library. I can't get that working but I can now upload files.